# CMake find_package(PythonLibs) not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, registry, cmake

I am trying to use `Python.h` in a C++ project compiled with g++. I am using CMake to generate proper include/lib links. I am using the built-in feature

```
find_package(PythonLibs REQUIRED)
```

but cannot get it working. I have been looking in `FindPythonLibs.cmake` to see what CMake was looking for and I found some registry keys that were missing on my machine. For example in the `PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR` section : `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Python\\PythonCore\\${_CURRENT_VERSION}\\InstallPath]/include`

Here is what I found in my registry :

- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Python.CompiledFile`
- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Python.File`
- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Python.NoConFile`

I have my Python files installed in `C:/Python33` and `find_package(PythonInterp)` is working fine (maybe because it finds the .exe file without having to hit the registry). Seems like some things are missing...  Is there a quick way to fix this ?

[Setup] : Python 3.3.2, Win8 64bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a 32-bit MinGW and a 64-bit Python distribution... I installed the 32-bit Python distribution and now find_package(PythonLibs) is working.